# MySQL full text search for Scandinavian Characters ø æ

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, full-text-search, multilingual

This is the only SO q/a I can find on this subject but it doesn't seem to answer the question: [Fulltext search with nordic letters (æ, ø, å)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407238/fulltext-search-with-nordic-letters-%C3%A6-%C3%B8-%C3%A5)

In MySQL I have a user called "John Nørbæk".

I would like to be able to match this user when searching for:

"Noerbaek", "Nørbaek" or "Noerbæk"

(It would be nice to be able to match for "Norbaek" as well, but my Googling has suggested that ø is equivalent to "oe" rather than "o" so it now feels wrong to request that).

I am using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

I have created an SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5be3d4/3

Every result i've come up with online seems to be related to PHP and replacing those characters with a str_replace, but if what is in my database is "Nørbæk" then that's not that helpful.

I can't do something like this because the matched string needs to be in the full text index:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (REPLACE(`name`, 'æ', 'ae'))
AGAINST ('Nørbaek' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This would work, but would of course fail when searching for something like "Michael" because it would be converted to Michæl so that's out of the question.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (`name`)
AGAINST (REPLACE('Nørbaek', 'ae', 'æ') IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

So i'm all out of ideas, there's got to be a better way to match these characters right?

I am more interested in usability than anything else.

As an example if an elderly user wants to find their "Dr Nørbæk" they need to be able to type something in that will find him and not simply be told to learn how to type an "ø".

Edit 1:
One comment has suggested that I should use `utf8mb4_swedish_ci` but I have names from all kinds of languages in my database, including Chinese, so I figure I should be using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` although i'll be honest in saying that I simply always use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as a "best practice" without fully understanding the reasons why.

Edit 2:
A comment suggested `utf8_unicode_520_ci` and that seems to work, as seen in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a604e/4 I will need to do some more tests to see what other affects it has.

Comment: First of all, to get scandinavian behaviour, you need to use a scandinavian collation, e.g. `utf8mb4_swedish_ci`. I don't know scandinavian, but a quick test revealed `ø = ö != oe` (and `æ = ä != ae`). Can you recheck/verify the expected behaviour `ö = oe` for your search? A collation that has `ö = oe` is `german2`, but it will have `o = ø != ö = oe` (and `æ = ae = ä != a`). In general: MySQL will not give you a simple way to support multiple languages (where e.g. the norwegian, german and french users all find their little perks at the same time), you may need a little more work

Comment: Hmm I didn't realise I would need utf8mb4_swedish_ci I rather naively thought that utf8mb4_unicode_ci was a catch all.

Comment: I was basing ø = oe on this from wikipedia: "In other languages that do not have the letter as part of the regular alphabet, or in limited character sets such as ASCII, ø is frequently replaced with the digraph "oe"" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98

Comment: Well, as I said, I don't know what scandinavian users expect. And, probably more relevant, what your requirements say and/or what your target audience is. As mentioned, to make your search support multiple languages, you may need to do a bit more work (e.g. store different variations or normalized versions of your data), the simple MySQL fulltext search will probably not cut it. See e.g. how more [specialized search engines](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/language-analysis.html#scandinavian) do it (according to which, `ø=ö=o` in Sweden, and `ø=oo, oe, o or ao(?)` in Denmark/Norway).

Comment: Basically it's far more complicated than I thought, I assumed it was as simple as e and è which mysql full text search seems to handle just fine, but apparently it's not.

Comment: [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) is a rundown on which collations treat which things as equal.  Swedish, Icelandic, or Danish might be useful.  Or consider `utf8_unicode_520_ci`; but that considers `ae=æ` and `O=Ø`.

Comment: None of the MySQL collations seem to treat `ø=oo`

Comment: @RickJames `utf8_unicode_520_ci` seems to work as shown in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a604e/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John demonstrated,

```
MATCH(col) AGAINST('Nørbæk' ...)
```

succeeds for

- `IN BOOLEAN MODE` and `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`.
- `col = 'Norbaek'`,
- other variants of `Nørbæk` in the `AGAINST`,
- 5.6 (and presumaby later versions),
- with collation `utf8_unicode_520_ci` (or `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`).

http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html and http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html show the following equivalence classes for the 520 collation for either character set:

```
A=a=ª=À=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ă=ă=Ą=ą
ae=Æ=æ
O=o=º=Ò=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=Ø=ò=ó=ô=õ=ö=ø=Ō=ō=Ŏ=ŏ=Ő=ő=Ơ=ơ
oe=Œ=œ
```

So, given that collation, there is no need to do the `REPLACEs`; instead specify that collation (utf8_unicode_520_ci or utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci) for the column